# How to import OldSchool scripts into ES6 app

Tags: javascript

Old scripts designed to be used directly with < script > tag, use various global variables and some features which don't work inside ES6 with default strict mode.

For Example:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'importScripts' on 'WorkerGlobalScope': Module scripts don't support importScripts().
```

How can we hypothetically do something like this:

```
var coolModule = magicImport( 'oldstyle_library.js' )
```

Or better yet:

```
var coolIsolatedModule = magicImportWrapContain( 'oldstyle_library.js' )
```

The desired outcome is some way to import ES5 or old style javascript into a neatly isolated object just like ES6 import module.  Wild and weird solutions welcome.

Comment: There is no other way than touching such old code bases. The good new is, it already should be enough to prefix every needed function / object / variable with an [`export`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export) statement. The other good news ... Since the old code seems to be of importance, it already might be well written in a maintainable way, and if not, then there is the chance of finally refactoring it.

Comment: Are you sure? es-shim? es-build? esinstall? lavamoat? iframe adapter?

Answer (score 0):

Create a script DOM element, set the script src, insert it into body. do next in event 'onload'.it's like

```
const script = document.createElement("script");
script.src = 'oldstyle_library.js';
script.onload = function() { //get the library exports here };
document.body.appendChild(script);
```

but it's asynchronous.You can use Promise to implement the magicImport function.

One implement for example:

```
function magicImport(src, globalVar) { 
  return new Promise(resolve => {
     let exports = window[globalVar];
     if(exports) {
        resolve(exports);
     } else {
        const script = document.createElement("script");
        script.src = src;
        script.onload = function() { resolve(window[globalVar]); };
        document.body.appendChild(script); 
     }
  });
}

magicImport("jquery.js", "jQuery").then(jQuery => { 
   //do what you want with jQuery
});
// or use async/await
const jQuery = await magicImport("jquery.js", "jQuery");
//do what you want with jQuery
```

Comment: This most probably will lead to global namespace conflicts.

Comment: yeah, but import some oldstyle js librarys is not common, it fits when you got no way to do.

Comment: The OP is looking for a way to import ... _"Old scripts designed to be used directly with `<script/>` tag"_ ... into an ES6 app. This means, such scripts of cause can be imported into a browser either via `<script/>` or the way you proposed. There is nothing new about it. The OP is looking for a way to import such old scripts into a **module capable** (most probably) development environment like node. There is no chance of getting such code into a module environment than actually making it a module. And the easiest way is the prefixing of every needed function/object/variable with `export`.

Comment: Thanks @Taurz , can you expand/elaborate on this line:
script.onload = function() { //get the library exports here };

Comment: Oldstyle libraries often bind their exports to properties of global instance like `window`.For example, import jquery by script tag, you can get JQuery by using `window.jQuery` or 'window.$', so in onload callback function just get the exports by using `window.libraryExport` , the property  'libraryExport' depends on what library you imported.But as Peter Seliger sugguested, `This most probably will lead to global namespace conflicts`.

Comment: @taurz This is cool thinking. I try to see if this works. I wish stackoverflow had more outside the box thinking like this.